# Share text between iPhone and other phones using wifi

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, networking, wifi

Is it possible to send and receive data between iPhone and other phones such as blackberry or android over wifi. I am on the move it to create an iPhone app with the above functionality. Can any one has previous experience in this, or any sample codes to do this. I have searched a lot but couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: Take a look at **bonjour** "Zero configuration network" which is originaly from apple and it's also open source. Implementation for Android and BB is available (on the net as some samplecodes, google it). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by using a server application. So the iphone pushes the data to the server and the other devices are either getting push notifications or something similar or simply poll for the data.

Without a server, you have the trouble of finding the other devices. If its safe to assume they are all on the same subnet, then you could use a UDP broadcast to do this.

There's many ways of doing this, every one with its own pitfalls. So there's no generic answer to this question without knowing in more detail what's the purpose of it.